# PHP querying whois database

Tags: php, whois

i am connecting to tld specific whois databases for whois information.
Some just return:

```
Domain: domain.de
Status: connect
```

.com works fine for example
How can i still get the full whois information?

my code:

```
$lookup = "";
    if(strlen($whois) > 0) {
        $fp = fsockopen($whois, 43, $errno, $errstr);
    } else {
        $fp = fsockopen(trim($server->server), 43, $errno, $errstr);
    }

    if (!$fp) {
        echo "ERROR: $errno - $errstr<br />\n";
    }
    fwrite($fp, "".$domain."\r\n");
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $lookup .= fgets($fp);
    }
    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: You do realize that most people who feed WHOIS data have active countermeasures to stop you from doing this very thing, right?

Comment: why? it should be legit for everyone to check freely available whois data

Comment: what abous just parsing `whois` command line tool ?

Comment: You further agree not to use this data to enable high volume, automated or robotic electronic processes designed to collect or compile this data for any purpose, including mining this data for your own personal or commercial purposes.
https://who.godaddy.com/?ci=8926

Comment: nobody said that i will do this.

Comment: Many country-specific registries will not give you full WHOIS records via port 43 queries. Some may give you nothing at all. You _have_ to go to their websites instead (and often enter captcha codes). Each one operates slightly differently.

Answer (score 0):

`.de` operates at `whois.denic.de`. By default, while connecting to `whois.denic.de` on 43 they don't disclosure privacy information about domain owner. Terms and conditions says:

```
% The DENIC whois service on port 43 never discloses any information concerning
% the domain holder/administrative contact. Information concerning the domain
% holder/administrative contact can be obtained through use of our web-based
% whois service available at the DENIC website:
% http://www.denic.de/en/domains/whois-service/web-whois.html
```